# Double integral with multiple conditions

Tags: integration, area

I want to calculate the area enclosed by:

$ y_1 \leq y \leq y_2 $

$ x_1 \leq x \leq x_2 $

$ x^2 \leq (r^2 - y^2) $

But I do not know how can I combine these boundaries in a double integral.

Comment: You want all the points within the rectangle determined by the first two conditions **that also are** within the circle determined by the last condition. Of course, it all depends on what exactly $\;x_i, y_i, r\;$ are.

Comment: Yes, can I write an expression valid for any $x_i, y_i, r$?

Comment: I don't think so. You can write an expression for every possibility, and there are several and it'd be quite long, imo.